# defaultChecked; why this property even exist?

Tags: javascript

Taking JavaScript this semester. I cannot grasp how this property can be useful at all. This property gives a Boolean value of true IF the checked attribute was used in  tag for the check box object...BUT if I am the one writing the program ...I should know if I wrote that into the program correct? I just do not see the logic in this property. Anybody have a better reason for the use of it?

Comment: It allows a script to determine whether a check-box has changed from its initial state, without having to keep track of that initial state. So: convenience and simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to answer your question, "Don't I know?". Of course not. If you are thinking of a form that is only used to add records, I could see your point but forms are also used to update records and we have no idea what the initial value is for any given record that may need to be updated.

The next thing to understand is that the same concept applies to more than check boxes. For example the text input elements have a "defaultValue" property that parallels the logic of default checked property.

The next point, is these properties would be better understood by novices had they been named "initialxyz" rather than "defaultxyz". Novices think that they are used to identify what should be sent to the server if not populated by the user but that is not what they are at all. They are the initial value, as sent by the server to the client, before the user starts interacting with the screen.

To answer your larger question, these propertied are extremely useful in two cases. The first has already been mentioned which is the "reset" button or as I jokingly call it the "oops" button or "start over". That can occur at the record level that resets every element on the form but it can be used on a field by field basis where only the field that has focus is reset. For example, the escape key is often used for this purpose.  The second use for this is to know if the form is "clean" (unchanged) or dirty (changed, in at least one small way somewhere). This is used in too commentary places that you did not think about. The first is to avoid submitting a form with no changes to the server. Why waste resources. The complementary is to pop up the "are you sure you want to lose your changes" when someone attempts to navigate away from a form with changes. You walk the form and compare the current valued to the initial value for each element. If no elements changed the form is clean and allow the user to leave without a prompt. If at least one element is different than it's initial value and take appropriate action which might be to prompt to confirm leaving or it might be to submit the form changes to the server before leaving or something that neither of us have thought of yet.

Answer (score 0):

One scenario would be when you are creating checkboxes dynamically, on-the-fly, in your code. The creation may be dependent on a couple of parameters, some of them depending in turn on selections by the user, from the current screen/page.
You may wish to set what is the state of these newly created checkboxes by default, before the user performs any actions on them.

Exemplifying: Say you have a textbox where the user has to tell you how many new checkboxes you should create for whatever further actions. Then after the user enters the input, your javascript creates N checkboxes, accordingly. And their initial state is set according to "defaultChecked".

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically, you might have a form with lots of fields written in html, and you may want to have a "reset" button which resets all of the form fields back to their initial values. (I don't really know why that used to be a common form button, I've never seen a use for it...) The code to reset checkboxes would then be:

```
input.checked = input.defaultChecked;
```

which would be the same for all checkboxes, and then you wouldn't need to track the difference between default checked and no default checked ones separately.

Really though, it doesn't appear to have much use, and I've never used it before.

Comment: "*...would be the same for all [check-boxes]*" - and radio inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Just yesterday I found myself using this same attribute. It comes in very handy when trying to set certain values to default.

Have you ever signed up for something ad then found yourself receiving TONS of unwanted newsletters? or you install one thing and two more things start installing? This happens because there was an option somewhere with a checkbox that had the checked attribute to make that decision for you.

Mostly it is used to make decisions for the user. Comes in handy sooner than later!

BTW: Welcome to the sweet world of JavaScript!

Comment: Thanks Junior. I must admit, I am having a hard time following the logic in JavaScript. C++ was so much easier to me. It's coming slowly, but at least I'm moving forward 